# Disable Secure Forms in config.php

Tags: config, secureforms

I can't log into my control panel and I think the issue is related to "secure forms" being enabled. How do I disable "secure forms" in the EE config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following into the EE config.php file to disable "secure forms":

```
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

Answer (score 6):

As of 2.8 it's changed slightly... So if you want to disable "secure forms" you'll need to use this in config.php instead of what is posted elsewhere.

```
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y";
```

More info here: http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/sessions-login-modals-and-secure-forms-in-expressionengine-2.8